# Ubuntu 18.04 dpkg/apport problem

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, python-2.7

I recently updated python2 on my system, and now whenever I attempt to update or install any packages, I get an error of the following sort:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apport
Suggested packages:
  apport-gtk | apport-kde
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/124 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 283944 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.prerm: 22: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.prerm: pyclean: Permission denied
dpkg: warning: old apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 22: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 new apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed apport package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried updating and upgrading, removing apport and reinstalling, and updating reinstalling python2 again. I have also tried reinstalling apport and removing

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4_all.deb
```

After reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865331/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-apport-2-20-1) post, I have the following error trying to update or install any packages on the system:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python-configparser (3.5.0-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-configparser.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-configparser.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package python-configparser (--configure):
 installed python-configparser package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Setting up apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 installed apport package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Setting up python-pip (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pip.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pip.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 installed python-pip package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-configparser
 apport
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I know that error 126 indicates that the package is corrupt or incomplete, and I have seen some solutions which involve removing the packages forcefully, for example,

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq PACKAGE_NAME
```

but I am concerned about removing python packages which may be integral to the operation of the system, so I am hesitant to remove them.

**EDIT**

I have solved this problem by [reinstalling Ubuntu with a live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation), without reformatting the partition. Only installed packages needed to be restored.